# Using two proxy servers at the same time?

Tags: proxy

I'm connected to my dorm's LAN using a proxy and now i need to use intercepting proxies (WebScarab, Burp Suite, etc). However i'm not sure how i can set those up when i'm already using a proxy.

Comment: Please ask your question clearly inside body.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you end up *chaining* one proxy to the next. Fiddler, for instance, does this for you automatically when it starts up. It takes whatever proxy you have configured in IE and uses this as the "upstream" proxy. Then it sets itself as the system/browser proxy.

So your traffic goes Client->Fiddler->UpstreamProxy->WebServer
[image: Proxy Chaining]

Most other proxy tools have a way to manually configure an upstream proxy.